# Personalize snackbar without using snackbar from component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, snackbar

my issue is really simple but I can't seem to find any way to make it work.
Here is my snackbar method :

```
this.snackBar.open('The selected object cannot be deleted. The object2 with' + '\n' + ' the following IDs ' + A + ' depend on it. They need to be deleted first.', '', {
      duration: 4000,
    });
```

Is there a simple way to add new line (simply adding `+ '\n'` is not working) to the message displayed on the snackbar without using open from component nor open from template ?

Thanks !

Comment: please refer to this. there might be a solution: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11239

Comment: Well this is exactly what i dont want to use : openFromComponent.

Comment: well, there was a pre-wrap too but doesnt seem to work.  sorry out of options. fromtemplate seems one of the more clean solutions but if its not an option.  dont know.  anything else will be more of a hack i think

Comment: Yes it seems so haha thank you anyway !